# Android Volley Request - 403 Error, but works in browser

Tags: android, android-volley

i'm trying to request a public website. In this example https://shop.rewe.de/mc/api/markets-stationary/98693

The response is a JSON Object with local stores.

If i do that in a clean Browser (deleted cookies and cached data) it works fine. I used a websniffer addon in Chrome so i was able to see the request with its headers.

[image]

So there are just 3 header params. So now I would like to do this with volley and a simple own StringRequest class where i just overwrote the getheaders()  Method to set these 3 params.

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders(){
    HashMap<String, String> _headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    _headers.put("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
    _headers.put("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36");
    _headers.put("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
    return _headers;
}
```

Now i just do an request with volley

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap
    Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
    RequestQueue requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
    requestQueue.start();
    
    String url ="https://shop.rewe.de/mc/api/markets-stationary/98693";
    StringRequestImpl stringRequest = new StringRequestImpl(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Do something with the response
                    String tst = response.toString();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    String tst = error.toString();
                }
            });
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

What i get back is an com.android.volley.AuthFailureError with Status Code 403

I thought i was doing exactly the same like my Chrome browser. But why it works in Chrome but not with volley? Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0):

For people who are interessted. The server owner is now using a cloudfare bot protection. I don't know how they identify a simple request as bot but maybe i find a solution.